# Combining multiple array with all array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I want to combine multiple arrays to make specific format.

```
$fieldArray=[];
$fieldArray['field_val']['key_1']=array('1');
$fieldArray['field_val']['key_2']=array('1','2','3','4');
$fieldArray['field_val']['key_3']=array('5','6','7','8');
$fieldArray['field_val']['key_4']=array('9','10','11','12');
$fieldArray['field_val']['key_5']=array('30');
```

Result Should be

```
1,1,5,9,30 
1,2,6,10,30 
...and so on
```

I have tried the following code. But it not give me the correct results.

```
echo '<pre>';
$i=0;
$newArray=[];
foreach($fieldArray['field_val'] as $key=>$values){
    if($i==0){
        $orderId=$values[0];
    }
    array_unshift($values,$orderId);
    $newArray[]=$values;
$i++;
}

array_shift($newArray);
array_pop($newArray);
print_r($newArray);
```

I need the following output.

```
1,1,5,9,30
1,2,6,10,30 and so on
```

Comment: Why the second element is `1,2,6,10,30` and not `2,6,10`?

Comment: What if an array has two elements? And not one or four? If the number is either 1 or N, this is quite straightforward, but what if its 1, N-1 and N elements in the arrays?

Comment: i want to combine first element of first array with another array so that it will become 1,2,6,10,30

Comment: @SurajKumar  again the same thing -> what about `30`? it will be add also everytime?

Comment: better to explain logic behind what you are trying to achieve, because it's hard for us to understand that

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes 30 will be add everytime

Comment: What if `$fieldArray['field_val']['5']=array('30');` is instead with one more value, `$fieldArray['field_val']['5']=array('30', '45');` then what? Use 30 first, then 45 for the other 3?

Comment: @AlivetoDie I want to submit the form with one order,multiple items and total quantity data.

Comment: @Qirel No last array will have only single element everytime.

Comment: @SurajKumar  then better to change form elements `name`  attribute so that you can get things by default, no need to do stuff/ very less stuff needs to do at php end

Comment: @dWinder i want to combine first element of first element and first element of last element with all other array's element and make new array which gives me the expected result.

Comment: @SurajKumar  SHOW YOUR FROM HTML PLEASE. add in your question

Comment: @AlivetoDie actually form's element is dynamic ```$formField='<input value="'.$feildData['allData']['as_fl_set_id_'.$field['as_fl_set_id']].'" type="text" '.$mandatory.' class="control-input '.$extraClass.' as_fl_set_id_'.$field['as_fl_set_id'].'" name="field_val[as_fl_set_id_'.$field['as_fl_set_id'].'][]" />';```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once check the output of this, As I can see, you are kinda transposing array.
I first transposed and wrote a snippet for your requirement.

```
$temp = array_map(null, ...$fieldArray['field_val']); // transposing array
foreach ($temp as $key => &$value) {
    foreach ($value as $key1 => &$value1) {
        // checking if empty
        if(empty($value1)){ 
            // fetching key1 value from first array and 
            // mapping it to empty values for all other arrays except first
            $value1 = $temp[0][$key1]; 
        }
    }
}
echo implode("\n", array_map(function ($value) { // replace with br if web
  return implode(",", $value);
}, $temp));
```

[**Demo**](https://3v4l.org/tXeb4)

> **Note**: Must have data from the initial index.

**Explanation**:

1. Please see this [link](https://3v4l.org/62K9a) how I transposed it,
2. Then I took the first array as my base array to play with other values
3. Then I mapped with first and last values with other values with empty values.

**EDIT**

```
function transpose($array) {
    array_unshift($array, null);
    return call_user_func_array('array_map', $array);
}
$temp = transpose($fieldArray['field_val']); // transposing array

function flipDiagonally($arr) {
    $out = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $subarr) {
        foreach ($subarr as $subkey => $subvalue) {
            $out[$subkey][$key] = $subvalue;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please explain the code.

Comment: Isn't inline doc enough or shall I explain more?

Comment: No problem,  I will try to understand. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: I wrote some inline doc, gave some explanation list out explanation, does it solves your problem?

Comment: This problem is occur when running this code ```Cannot unpack array with string keys```

Comment: Check my edit portion of answer and use that function instead of my way of transposing your array.

Comment: But your second option is also showing me the same error